# How to write "System.Collections.Hashtable" variable in Azure DevOps PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, hashtable

I'm having a variable of type `System.Collections.Hashtable` I want to write this value in azure DevOps variable in Powershell script and need to use the variable in the below tasks.

Variable created in azure DevOps: `header`

**Task 1**

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $env:tenant_id
$head = $null
$head = @{}
$head = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=headers]$head")
```

**Task 2**

```
Write-Host "Header is " $env:headers

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $env:headers -Uri 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups'
```

But the issue in Task 2 is

> Header is  System.Collections.Hashtable 
>   Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot
>   bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Collections.IDictionary".

Since the value of the header is simply assigning the string of `System.Collections.Hashtable` and not the actual value

Comment: Have you tried using the -AsString switch on Get-PowerBIAccessToken?  This should write the value of the access token to the $env:headers variable rather than the type. You can then construct the hashtable in Task 2

Comment: @NickGraham sorry new to PowerShell, could you please provide an example on how to use the -AsString. ?

Comment: $head = Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString

Comment: You might find it easier to get the access token and call Invoke-RestMethod in the same task

Comment: @NickGraham thanks for your answer, actually in the same task i dont have any issue, issue is only with the next task. As per you I've converted it to string.
Now how can i reconvert it to the Hashtable in the next task ?

Comment: You’ll need to take a look at the structure of the hash table that is returned by Get-PowerBIAccessToken (without the -AsString switch). Then create a new hashtable with the same property(s).  Create empty hashtable `$headers = @{}`. Then add the property `$headers[“PropertyName”] = $env:headers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call Invoke-RestMethod in the same task you avoid the complexity of writing the token into an Azure DevOps variable.

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $env:tenant_id
$head = $null
$head = @{}
$head = Get-PowerBIAccessToken

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $head -Uri 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups'
```